# create_function deprecated in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, function, deprecated

Please can anybody re-write this function for me for php 7.4

```php
private function flattenArray($array)
{
    $objTmp = (object)['aFlat' => []];

    array_walk_recursive($array, create_function('&$v, $k, &$t', '$t->aFlat[] = $v;'), $objTmp);

    return $objTmp->aFlat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it..

```php
private function flattenArray($array)
{
    $objTmp = (object)['aFlat' => []];

    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$v, $k, &$t){$t->aFlat[] = $v;}, $objTmp);

    return $objTmp->aFlat;
}
```