# WP-CLI Error for Slider Revolution Plugin

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

When running commands for WP-CLI I see the following error message related to the Revolution Slider Plugin. Does anyone know a way to resolve this issue or go around it?

**Slider Revolution Plugin Version:** 5.4.5

**Error Message:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_function() in /var/www/html/test/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php:258
```

**WP Info:**

```
-bash-4.2$ wp --info
OS: Linux 3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 3 15:06:38 UTC 2021 x86_64
Shell:  /bin/bash
PHP binary: /usr/bin/php
PHP version:    8.0.2
php.ini used:   /etc/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
WP-CLI vendor dir:  phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:   /var/www/html/test
WP-CLI packages dir:
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 2.4.0
-bash-4.2$
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_function() in /var/www/html/test/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php:258
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/test/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider.php(87): RevSliderFunctionsWP::registerWidget('RevSliderWidget')
#1 /var/www/html/test/wp-settings.php(391): include_once('/var/www/html/i...')
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1237): require('/var/www/html/i...')
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1158): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(23): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(74): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process(Object(WP_CLI\Bootstrap\BootstrapState))
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('phar:///usr/loc...')
#8 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('phar:///usr/loc...')
#9 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/test/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 258
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_function() in 

/var/www/html/test/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php:258
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/test/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider.php(87): RevSliderFunctionsWP::registerWidget('RevSliderWidget')
#1 /var/www/html/test/wp-settings.php(391): include_once('/var/www/html/i...')
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1237): require('/var/www/html/i...')
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1158): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(23): WP_CLI\Runner->start()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(74): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process(Object(WP_CLI\Bootstrap\BootstrapState))
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap()
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php(11): include('phar:///usr/loc...')
#8 /usr/local/bin/wp(4): include('phar:///usr/loc...')
#9 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/test/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 258
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured out that the "create_function()" method has been deprecated and removed in PHP 8.0.

See PHP Documentation as well as similar issue below for more details.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

[create_function deprecated in PHP 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132303/create-function-deprecated-in-php-7-4)

Discovered by reviewing the Slider Revolution Changelog that the plugin needs to be updated to be compatible with PHP 8.0.

[Slider Revolution Changelog](https://www.sliderrevolution.com/documentation/changelog/)

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! I don't have access to the latest version, so I reverted my version of PHP, which worked out